# не получается создать цвет и толщину границы поля ввода TextField

Tags: flutter, dart

Не получается создать цвет и толщину границы поля ввода TextField. У поля ввода можно создать границу

```
TextField(
 decoration: InputDecoration(
  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
 )
),
```

Я хочу изменить цвет и толщину границы, но **изменений не происходит ПОЧЕМУ-ТО**

```
TextField(
 decoration: InputDecoration(
  border: OutlineInputBorder(
   borderSide: BorderSide(
    color: Colors.pink,
    width: 5.0
   ),
  ),
 )
),
```

Далее, полный код и скриншоты

***main.dart***

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
 const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return MaterialApp(
   debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
   title: 'Name App',
   theme: ThemeData(
    primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
   ),
   home: Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
     title: const Text('Name Page'),
    ),
    body: const SafeArea(
     child: MyHomePage(),
    ),
   ),
  );
 }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
 const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

 @override
 _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

 @override
 void initState() {
  super.initState();
 }

 @override
 void dispose() {
  super.dispose();
 }

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return const Center(
   child: Padding(
    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
    child: TextField(
     decoration: InputDecoration(
      border: OutlineInputBorder(
       borderSide: BorderSide(
        color: Colors.pink,
        width: 5.0
       ),
      ),
     )
    ),
   ),
  );
 }

}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Касательно параметра **border** в [документации](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InputDecoration/border.html) написано:

> Only the border's shape is used.

Для изменения цвета обводки используйте параметры  **errorBorder, focusedBorder, enabledBorder, disabledBorder**.

Comment: Уважаемый Spatz! Огромное Вам спасибо! Теперь понятно.